# issue with getIntent()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

i need to open XML file with app that i am developing...the code is:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"  android:mimeType="*/*"  />
        </intent-filter>
```

and it is ok!

but i need, when i click on file, to get data from xml file.
In fragment if i write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getData().toString();
```

getIntent() is written in red by IDE...why?

Comment: Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `getIntent()` from a Fragment you need to get the Activity on which it's running. So try

`Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try `getActivity().getIntent()`.If outside Activity, you need an instance of the activity